# Java communication link failure when executing jar on Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, raspberry-pi

I created a java program on Windows with Eclipse which connect to a Mysql database hosted on Hostinger. I setup the connection to be able to access to the database from outside the world. When I run the program on Windows, I can access to my database with no error.

Then I exported this program to a jar file and created a localhost database on my Raspberry and try this program, it works perfectly.
Now when I change the database to access to the database on Hostinger, I get this error on my Raspberry :

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Why I'm getting this error on my Raspberry but not on windows ?
I'm running the program with the commmand : `java -jar myprogram.jar`

Here is the code :
`db.properties`

```
# mysql properties
mysql.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://ip_hostinger:3306/database_name
mysql.username=user
mysql.password=pwd
```

`Database.java`

```
public static MysqlDataSource getMySQLDataSource() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream is = null;
        MysqlDataSource ds = null;

        is = Database.class.getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
        props.load(is);

        ds = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
        ds.setURL(props.getProperty("mysql.url"));
        ds.setUser(props.getProperty("mysql.username"));
        ds.setPassword(props.getProperty("mysql.password"));

        return ds;
    }

        public static ArrayList<String> DatabaseSelect() throws IOException, SQLException {
        
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        ArrayList<String> resultSelect = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        try {
            con = getMySQLDataSource().getConnection();
            stm = con.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * from table");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String str = rs.getString("str");
                resultSelect.add(str);
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        }
        return resultSelect;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: If you managed to solve the problem, then post the solution as an **answer** and accept it after the timeout. Please don't edit solutions in the question itself. BTW: If this was the solution, then you probably have a highly outdated MySQL server version, and the better solution is to upgrade your MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by commenting these lines in file `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/conf/security/java.security`

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
     DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
     include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```